# "Резиновое" html письмо - проблемы с Yahoo, обходные варианты

Tags: html, email-layout, css

Добрый день. Имеется резиновое HTML письмо. Начинается оно с "оберточной" таблички, которая стремится занять всю доступную ширину, задать фон. Выглядит так:

`<table bgcolor="#f1f1f1" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
... 
</table>`

Внутри идет контентная часть письма с min и max width, которая благополучно центрируется.

В веб-интерфейсе yahoo.com письмо попадает в вот такой контекст:

`.thread-item.expanded .thread-body .body, 
.msg-body {
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}`

Что сплющивает письмо до min-width его центральной части. width: 100%; соответствено не дает никакого эффекта.

**Возможно ли как-то насильно растянуть письмо в таком случае?**

[Проблем на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNQuX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение. Нужно влепить **table-layout: fixed**; внешней таблице. Тут, правда, надо быть осторожные с тем, чтобы в этой внешней таблице был только один столбец.

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNQuX/2/)